# Laravel Sanctum/Vuex Uncaught Error Vue Router Navigation Guard

Tags: laravel, vue.js, authentication, vuex, vue-router

Can anyone advise on this issue?

I've got a Laravel app with a Vue front-end, connecting to the API using Laravel Sanctum. (within the same application) I'm trying to set up the authentication guards so routes can only be accessed after authentication with the API.

I'm connecting through the state action like so:

```
      async getAuthenticatedUser({ commit }, params) {
          await axios.get('api/auth-user', { params })
              .then(response => {
                  commit('SET_AUTHENTICATED', true)
                  commit('SET_AUTHENTICATED_USER', response.data)
                  localStorage.setItem('is-authenticated', 'true')

                  return Promise.resolve(response.data)
              })
              .catch(error => {
                  commit('SET_AUTHENTICATED', false)
                  commit('SET_AUTHENTICATED_USER', [])
                  localStorage.removeItem('is-authenticated')

                  return Promise.reject(error.response.data)
              })
      },
```

The state authenticated property is set as follows:

```
const state = () => ({
      authenticated: localStorage.getItem('is-authenticated') || false,
      authUser: [],
  })
```

I have the following guard checking the auth. If I'm not signed in the app correctly redirects me back to the login screen when I access a route with the requiresAuth attribute.

However when I attempt to log in, I get `Redirected when going from "/login" to "/dashboard" via a navigation guard.`

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (store.getters["Auth/isAuthenticated"]) {
      next()
      return
    }
    next('/login')
  }

  if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requiresVisitor)) {
    if (! store.getters["Auth/isAuthenticated"]) {
      next()
      return
    }
    next('/dashboard')
  }

  next()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's safe to ignore, and you are using vue-router `^3.4.0`, you can do:

```js
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

const { isNavigationFailure, NavigationFailureType } = VueRouter
...
this.$router.push(fullPath).catch(error => {
  if (!isNavigationFailure(error, NavigationFailureType.redirected)) {
    throw Error(error)
  }
})
```

Or handle it globally:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

const { push } = VueRouter.prototype

const { isNavigationFailure, NavigationFailureType } = VueRouter

VueRouter.prototype.push = function (location) {
  return push.call(this, location).catch(error => {
    if (!isNavigationFailure(error, NavigationFailureType.redirected)) {
      throw Error(error)
    }
  })
}

Vue.use(VueRouter)
```

For more details, please refer to [Navigation Failures](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-failures.html).